# Why Stack extends Vector in JDK?

Tags: java, oop

`Stack` is not a `Vector` then why Stack class is extending(is a relationship) Vector class in JDK, Stack suppose to work with `push()` & `pop()` operations, but because it extends Vector I am able to do `add()` and `remove()` operations over a stack.

I think rather extending Vector class, Stack class should use Vector class as a composition.

Comment: Similar discussion: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1156973?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Yes the link does contain what i want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Outmoded classes

Both `Stack` and `Vector` were included with the first release of Java. Java was rushed to market ahead of its time because of the Internet frenzy at that time.

Some of the classes bundled with those earliest versions of Java, such as the date-time classes, were not well thought-out. They had not been subjected to peer review and public scrutiny as were later libraries such as some produced through the [*Java Community Process*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process) and through open-source projects and industry consortium projects.

## Java Collections framework

The [Java Collections framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework?wprov=sfsi1) supplants both of these classes. Similarly, the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework supplants the old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`/`.Calendar`. The old classes remain in Java for backwards compatibility with existing apps but should not be used in new code.

| Legacy | Modern replacement |
| --- | --- |
| [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/Vector.html) | [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/List.html) such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) |
| [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/Stack.html) | [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) such as [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) & [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) |

The [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class documentation tells you this, clearly saying you should instead be using an implementation of the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface.

[image: diagram of classes in the Java Collections Framework]

Diagram is by Ramlmn, [published on Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Java.util.Collection_hierarchy.svg). Modified by me to indicate `Vector` & `Stack` being obsolete.

**Update:** Java 21 brought sequenced collections, adding more interfaces than seen in the chart above. See [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

[image: Java Collections interface hierarchy including sequenced collections]

Third-parties have created more collections interfaces and implementations:

- [*Google Guava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava)
- [*Eclipse Collections*](https://eclipse.dev/collections/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i found a better discussion on [Why does Stack extend Vector?](http://community.oracle.com/thread/1156973?start=0&tstart=0)